# Is there a way for Miis to instantly become sweethearts?

Tags: tomodachi-life

How can I get miis to instantly be sweethearts and to be happy, no matter what the compatibility meter says. I do not want to have to do anything with the time as it has already been played with.

Answer (score 2):

It's all random. If you pick "Go for it" when a Mii wants to confess to another Mii and the other Mii says something like "Sure", then they will be sweethearts and even one of them might want to [propose!](http://tomodachi.wikia.com/wiki/Proposal).

Let me know if this doesn't work for you or this answer wrong

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until a mii says that he/she has feelings for another Mii. When the other Mii says "Sure!" after the mii confesses to him/her, they will become sweethearts.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to get that to happen faster? That's the whole reason I added this question. To get it to happen faster.

Answer (score 0):

Well it will take one day to one week if the miis relation ship is working out just check there friendship rating if they don't have a sweetheart.

Answer (score -2):

Just wait till one of them confesses and then if the other side me says "sure" then they will become sweet hearts

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't get the Miis to *instantly* become sweethearts though, which is the whole point of the question ...